# How to do AngularJs view enter animation

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to create slide-in animation when a view is rendered in the angular app similar to [this sample](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-Animation-Article)

Here is my app http://plnkr.co/edit/nO7mfjx5iOUUyB0tZwIq?p=preview.
I copied all the css classes from the sample but I can't get the animation to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found some problem in your css style, I modify it like this:

```
.view-enter.ng-enter, .view-enter.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
}

.view-enter.ng-enter {
  opacity:1;
  left:100px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
.view-enter.ng-enter-active {
  left:0;
  opacity:1;
}

.view-enter.ng-leave {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  opacity:0;
}
.view-enter.ng-leave-active {
  left:-100px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

In your html file, you must add class in your ng-view directive element, like this:

```
<div ng-view class="view-enter"></div>
```

Comment: also, you can review documentation for ng-view.
http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView